# Hibernate.Integer cannot be resolved while using addScalar() method

Tags: sql, hibernate, compiler-errors, integer

```
String qry = select max(total) as max_marks from student;
SQLQuery sq = ses.createSQLQuery(qry);
sq.addScalar("max_marks",Hibernate.Integer);
```

Compilation Error:

```
Hibernate.Integer ---> Cannot be resolved
```

please specify What are the modifications i have to do?